# How to add second line text after colon in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Guys i want the second line text to be after the colon , how to do in notepad++ ?? or any other available ???

Data i have is below

```
SNO :
19110
BLKNAME :
SETHUBAVACHATRAM
DISTRICTNA : 
THANJAVUR
PANCHTYPE :  
VP
RVILLNAME :  
SEMBIYAMADEVIPATTINAM
TALUKNAME :  
Peravurani
```

Expecting to like this -

```
SNO : 19110
BLKNAME : SETHUBAVACHATRAM
DISTRICTNA : THANJAVUR
PANCHTYPE : VP
RVILLNAME : SEMBIYAMADEVIPATTINAM
TALUKNAME : Peravurani
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `:\s+`
- Replace with: `:`  # a colon followed by a space
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
:           # a colon
\s+         # 1 or more spaces (including linebreak)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
SNO : 19110
BLKNAME : SETHUBAVACHATRAM
DISTRICTNA : THANJAVUR
PANCHTYPE : VP
RVILLNAME : SEMBIYAMADEVIPATTINAM
TALUKNAME : Peravurani
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can most likely use this regular expression:

```
([^:]+):\s*(.*)
```

and make a replacement with:

```
$1: $2
```

and it might work.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/XK8VKN/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.